# How can I free Drawable memory in one Android Honeycomb Activity after a different Activity has started?

Tags: android, memory, android-activity, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have an Android Honeycomb application with two activities; the first one has a large `Bitmap` (taken from resources) as a background to the main `LinearLayout` and I have discovered that setting the background of this element to `null` from the activity's `onStop()` method can save a lot of memory—around 5MB, in fact.

However, this only seems to work when I click the "sleep" button on the device. If I do that the profiler shows the 5MB drops out of the world as easy as you like. If I start the second activity, the first activity's `onStop()` doesn't get hit until after the second activity's `onCreate()` and the profiler suggests that the `BitmapDrawable` is not removed from memory after all—so there it sits, five invisible useless megabytes, cluttering the place up.

I could remove this from `onPause()`, which might work better, but I'm also using the `onStop()` methods of various `Dialog` elements to null their background drawables as well. They don't seem to have `onPause()` methods.

Is there a recommended method for getting rid of these kinds of large, memory-consuming elements as an activity launches another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also for me OnPause event is a better place where put your "memory-free" code.

Here the event flow when you open a child activity from a parent activity

```
-- Open caller activity -- 
[ActCaller] 1311090884303: onCreate
[ActCaller] 1311090884572: onStart
[ActCaller] 1311090884699: onPostCreate savedInstanceState null
[ActCaller] 1311090884802: onResume
[ActCaller] 1311090884908: onPostResume
-- Open child activity --
[ActCaller] 1311090926270: onSaveInstanceState
[ActCaller] 1311090926374: onPause
  [ActChild] 1311090926556: onCreate
  [ActChild] 1311090926703: onStart
  [ActChild] 1311090926807: onPostCreate savedInstanceState null
  [ActChild] 1311090926911: onResume
  [ActChild] 1311090927014: onPostResume
[ActCaller] 1311090927508: onStop
```

As you already noticed, parent's onStop is called only after complete child creation.

What about calling memory-free code from two different location? Consider that dialogs, generally, don't completely cover calling activity, so preserving it's background has a sense.
Maybe a flag can be set when you open a new activity instead of a dialog, and OnPause logic will drop background only when a new activity is launched, and not a dialog.

Comment: That's actually very helpful generally, thank you—the interlocking of two activity lifecycles isn't very well documented that I can see! My only slight concern is that using `onPause()` might end up removing the drawable in circumstances where I don't want it removed. I guess I can only try it though :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no special way for handling such things, it's regular java way:

> Objects are garbage collected at an ***unknown time in future*** if they are
>   no longer referenced.

Just don't keep a reference to anything you don't need, and you will be fine.

Check this video for great info on this:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk

Comment: That doesn't work in this case: I have removed all **explicit** references to these objects, but in one case some **implicit** references are kept. In one situation the method I have described for getting rid of the implicit references works; in another situation, it doesn't. I am trying to work out why, because I need to remove these implicit references.

Comment: @AndrewWyld: Use MAT to determine exactly what the "implicit reference" is.

Comment: I have done and can tell you: the background `LinearLayout` contains a reference to a `Bitmap` (as described in the original question). Calling `setBackgroundDrawable(null)` from `onStop()` frees this reference if you hit the power button (triggering a sleep state) but not if you launch another `Activity` with an `Intent`; however it does work from `onPause()`. This suggests you can't change the background of a `View` when it's not part of the active context, so purging memory from `onStop()` doesn't work.

Comment: So do I just make my objects null? WIll that be memory efficient then?